# How to cover Else if part in test class

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I wrote a test class for trigger which is 60% covered but Else-if part not covered. Please suggest me how to cover Else-if part?

Trigger-

```
            for(Claim__c c :trigger.new){
              if(c.Company_Name__c != null){
                if(rollChildMap.get(c.Company_Name__c) != null && rollChildMap.get(c.Company_Name__c).size() > 0){
                    List<Claim__c> clmLst = new List<Claim__c>();
                    clmLst =  rollChildMap.get(c.Company_Name__c);
                    system.debug('clmLst==>'+clmLst);//debug

                    totalQ1 = 0;
                    totalQ2 = 0;
                    totalQ3 = 0;
                    totalQ4 = 0;

                    for(Claim__c cm :clmLst){
                        Integer month = cm.Start_Date__c.month();
                        system.debug('month'+month);//debug

                        Integer year = cm.CreatedDate.Year();
                        Integer year1 = System.Today().year();

                        system.debug('Year--->' +year); 
                         system.debug('Year1--->' +year);

                        if(rollMap.get(c.Company_Name__c) != null){


                          if(year == year1){    
                            if(month >= 1 && month <= 3){
                                if(cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c != null)
                                    totalQ1 += cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c;
                            }
                            else if(month >= 4 && month <= 6){
                                if(cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c != null)
                                    totalQ2 += cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c;
                            }
                            else if(month >= 7 && month <= 9){
                                if(cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c != null)
                                    totalQ3 += cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c;
                            }
                            else if(month >= 10 && month <= 12){
                                if(cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c != null)
                                    totalQ4 += cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c;
                            }
                          } 
                        }
                     }
                    system.debug('totalQ1==>'+totalQ1);//debug
                        rollmap.get(c.Company_Name__c).Q1_Utilized_Amount__c = totalQ1;
                            system.debug('rollMapQ1==>'+rollmap.get(c.Company_Name__c).Q1_Utilized_Amount__c);//debug
                        rollmap.get(c.Company_Name__c).Q2_Utilized_Amount__c = totalQ2;
                            system.debug('rollMapQ2==>'+rollmap.get(c.Company_Name__c).Q2_Utilized_Amount__c);//debug
                        rollmap.get(c.Company_Name__c).Q3_Utilized_Amount__c = totalQ3;
                            system.debug('rollMapQ3==>'+rollmap.get(c.Company_Name__c).Q3_Utilized_Amount__c);//debug
                        rollmap.get(c.Company_Name__c).Q4_Utilized_Amount__c = totalQ4;
                            system.debug('rollMapQ4==>'+rollmap.get(c.Company_Name__c).Q4_Utilized_Amount__c);//debug
                }
            }
        }
            update rollMap.Values();
        }

        //---------------------------------------------Delete-----------------------------------------------------//

        if(trigger.isDelete){
            Set<Id> oldIds = new Set<Id>();
            Map<Id, List<Claim__c>> rollChildMap = new Map<Id, List<Claim__c>>();
            Map<Id,Account> rollMap = new Map<Id,Account>();

            for(Claim__c c :trigger.old){
                if(c.Company_Name__c != null){
                    system.debug('c.Company_Name__c==>'+c.Company_Name__c);
                    oldIds.add(c.Company_Name__c);
                }
            }


            if(oldIds != null && oldIds.size() > 0){
                List<Account> accLst = [Select Id, Q1_Utilized_Amount__c, Q2_Utilized_Amount__c, Q3_Utilized_Amount__c, Q4_Utilized_Amount__c, (Select Id, Approved_Amount_USD__c, Start_Date__c from Claims__r) from Account where Id IN:oldIds];
                system.debug('accLst==>'+accLst);//debug
                if(accLst != null){
                    for(Account a : accLst){
                        rollMap.put(a.Id, a);
                    }
                }
                system.debug('rollMap==>'+rollMap);//debug
            }
            Double totalQ1;
            Double totalQ2;
            Double totalQ3;
            Double totalQ4;
            if(rollMap != null && rollMap.size() > 0){
                for(Account acc :rollMap.Values()){
                    rollChildMap.put(acc.Id, acc.Claims__r);
                }
            }
            for(Claim__c c :trigger.old){
              if(c.Company_Name__c != null){
                system.debug('rollChildMap.get(c.Company_Name__c).size()==>'+rollChildMap.get(c.Company_Name__c).size());
                if(rollChildMap.get(c.Company_Name__c) != null && rollChildMap.get(c.Company_Name__c).size() > 0){
                    List<Claim__c> clmLst = new List<Claim__c>();
                    clmLst =  rollChildMap.get(c.Company_Name__c);
                    system.debug('clmLst==>'+clmLst);//debug

                    totalQ1 = 0;
                    totalQ2 = 0;
                    totalQ3 = 0;
                    totalQ4 = 0;

                    for(Claim__c cm :clmLst){
                        Integer month = cm.Start_Date__c.month();
                        system.debug('month== '+month);//debug
                        system.debug('rollMap==>> '+rollMap.get(c.Company_Name__c));//debug
                        if(rollMap.get(c.Company_Name__c) != null){
                            if(month >= 1 && month <= 3){
                                if(cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c != null)
                                    totalQ1 += cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c;
                            }
                            else if(month >= 4 && month <= 6){
                                if(cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c != null)
                                    totalQ2 += cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c;
                            }
                            else if(month >= 7 && month <= 9){
                                if(cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c != null)
                                    totalQ3 += cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c;
                            }
                            else if(month >= 10 && month <= 12){
                                if(cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c != null)
                                    totalQ4 += cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c;
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            totalQ1 = 0;
                            totalQ2 = 0;
                            totalQ3 = 0;
                            totalQ4 = 0;

                            if(month >= 1 && month <= 3){
                                if(cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c != null)
                                    totalQ1 += cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c;
                            }
                            else if(month >= 4 && month <= 6){
                                if(cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c != null)
                                    totalQ2 += cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c;
                            }
                            else if(month >= 7 && month <= 9){
                                if(cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c != null)
                                    totalQ3 += cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c;
                            }
                            else if(month >= 10 && month <= 12){
                                if(cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c != null)
                                    totalQ4 += cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    system.debug('totalQ1==>'+totalQ1);//debug
                        rollmap.get(c.Company_Name__c).Q1_Utilized_Amount__c = totalQ1;
                            system.debug('rollMapQ1==>'+rollmap.get(c.Company_Name__c).Q1_Utilized_Amount__c);//debug
                        rollmap.get(c.Company_Name__c).Q2_Utilized_Amount__c = totalQ2;
                            system.debug('rollMapQ2==>'+rollmap.get(c.Company_Name__c).Q2_Utilized_Amount__c);//debug
                        rollmap.get(c.Company_Name__c).Q3_Utilized_Amount__c = totalQ3;
                            system.debug('rollMapQ3==>'+rollmap.get(c.Company_Name__c).Q3_Utilized_Amount__c);//debug
                        rollmap.get(c.Company_Name__c).Q4_Utilized_Amount__c = totalQ4;
                            system.debug('rollMapQ4==>'+rollmap.get(c.Company_Name__c).Q4_Utilized_Amount__c);//debug
                }       
            }
        }
            update rollMap.Values();
            system.debug('rollMap after update==>'+rollMap);//debug             
        }   
        }   
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest(seealldata=true)

public class Trigger_ClaimAmountOnAccountTest {

    public static testMethod void testQ1(){


        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'Partner Account';
        acc.Q1_Utilized_Amount__c = 10;
        acc.Q2_Utilized_Amount__c = 10;
        acc.Q3_Utilized_Amount__c = 10;
        acc.Q4_Utilized_Amount__c = 10;

        insert acc;


        Contact con = new Contact (LastName='TestContact', AccountId=acc.Id); 
        insert con; 

        Profile p2 = [SELECT Id From Profile where Name='Partners (Distributors)'];

        User u2 = new User(
        Alias = 'newUser',
        IsActive = true,
        Email='newuser2@testorg.com', 
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
        LastName='Testing',
        LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
        LocaleSidKey='en_US',
        ProfileId = p2.Id, 
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles',
        UserName='newuser2@testorg.com',
        ContactId = con.Id);

        insert u2; 

        Fund_Request__c fun = new Fund_Request__c();
        fun.Company_Name__c = acc.Id;
        fun.Status__c = 'Submitted';
        fun.Activity_Name__c = 'Activity1';
        fun.Activity_Type__c = 'Collateral & Advertising';
        fun.Target_Audience__c = 'Partners';
        fun.Objective_s__c = 'Partner Recruitment';
        fun.Objective_Others__c = 'XYZ';
        fun.Start_Date__c = Date.today();
        fun.End_Date__c = Date.today().addDays(5);
        fun.Activity_Venue_City_Country__c = 'India';
        fun.Total_Cost_USD__c = 2000;
        fun.Claim_Amount_USD__c = 1000;
        insert fun;

        Claim__c cm = new Claim__c();
        cm.Fund_Request_ID__c = fun.Id; 
        cm.Approved_Amount_USD__c = 10;
        cm.Supporting_Documents__c = 'Customer invoice to Axis';
        cm.Company_Name__c = acc.id;

        insert cm;
        update cm;
        delete cm;     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You write a separate method for each condition. One that covers the `If` and another that covers the `Else If`. Just adjust your data to make certain it meets the criteria needed to meet the `Else If` condition when you create the Test method to cover that part of your code. You do the same for each branch when you have multiple If, Else If statements.

Answer (score 0):

In this case,to cover the else-if blocks in the same method:

You are performing the whole if-else for all the claim__c records in the list clmList. So each claim__c record has a field called "Start_Date__c" . You also populate the clmList from RollChildMap. 
Now make sure that the clmList has 4 such claim records:

1. The Start_Date__c has a date whose month is 1,2 or 3
2. The Start_Date__c has a date whose month is 4,5 or 6
3. The Start_Date__c has a date whose month is 7,8 or 9
4. The Start_Date__c has a date whose month is 10,11 or 12.

The input claim__c record should have "Company_Name__c" such that, when we try to get the corresponding list of claim__c from the rollChildMap, it gives a list of claim records and the list contains the above for mentioned type of claim records.

Ensure this and all the else-if blocks can be covered in the same method. Hope this helps.